# Is it right to read the event sourcing when we want history?

Tags: c#, cqrs

My application use CQRS architecture. Everything is performed through my aggregates, thus each user's action is saved as an event in my event source store.

Now, I need a new form which shows the history of every action performed in my application, so what should I do ?

1 - Read the event store ? How ?

2 - Publish an event in each of my domain handler like "SavedToHistory(User user, Action action, DateTime date) then in my event handlers, store it in my read data model  ?

Comment: Are you using the event store to drive any business logic? If you are then there is probably something missing from your domain.

Comment: Just a note: CQRS is not event sourcing :) --- Since the event store is probably using some serialized object I would go with a query store (your option 2).

Comment: @Even Roux: Sure, and yeah you're right, my events are serialized :) I was also thinking about using option 2.

Comment: @David Neale no, I don't. My logic is in my domain. What I'm curious to know is if we could query the event store to use it, as it already contains a list of every actions performed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the whole idea of CQRS is to have separation of reading and writing, and of storage (reading vs writing again), I think the most consistent action you can take is to write denormalized history data to the Read database and read it from there rather than trying to read it from the Event Store.

This can be straightforward; you can write a general denormalizer that can write any new event in the Event Store to a denormalized version in the Read database, or you can have specialized denormalizers -- it depends on how you want to display history in your application.

Either way, write denormalized versions of your events to the Read DB so that your application will not need to know exactly how events are structured in the Event Store.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to show full history for developers, then you can just replicate all events to a domain log (read model with aggregated list of all events that developers are allowed to see).

If you need to show history to the users, then showing deserialized events would not work that well. Instead you can have a read model that maps each event to an activity with some human readable description. That's what we do for facebook-like "what's new" feeds.

Same rules of managing read models apply in both cases - if you change rules for aggregating events or mapping them to the human-readable activities, then just drop the read model and rebuild it from the history completely.

Comment: Hi @Rinat Abdullin, thanks for your answer. It's appreciated. There's a little detail I'd like to question you in your answer. In both cases, as it is an history of actions, why not update my read model instead of drop it ? That's to say, in my UI, I handle the events corresponding to user's actions and just need to insert a new row in my read model. What do you think ? It's a bit more efficient than dropping the table, reloading events and filling the table.

Comment: John, normally you just add new rows, of course. However, if you happen to change how rows are generated (i.e.: instead of "account created" you want to print "account created by a partner X") and you want the change to apply back in time, then you would need to rebuild the view completely.